# TYPO3 Upgrade from v9 to V10 lazy loading error

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I’m trying to update a TYPO3 site from version 9.5.30 to version 10.0.0.

I have the following error:

> (1/1) #1549446998 LogicException TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager can
> not be injected/instantiated during ext_localconf.php loading. Use
> lazy loading instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really update to TYPO3 10.0.0? You can and should update directly to version 10.4 (10.4.20 as of today).

According to the TYPO3 bug tracker ([#88843](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88843), [#88975](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88975)), there were problems which have been fixed already a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter Kraume, How can I do? Do you have the steps to follow please?

Comment: The update to 10.4 is done exactly the same way as you did for the update to 10.0. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/Upgrade/Index.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter Kraume, Yes but my update to Typo3 v10.0.0 has never worked. I still have the error: (1/1) #1549446998 LogicException
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager can not be injected/instantiated during ext_localconf.php loading. Use lazy loading instead.